# Change time format in Time picker of Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, timepicker

I want to change time format (12/24 hour) using javascript or jquery. I have used bootstrap 3 time picker from http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-time picker/ and its working fine.

Now i want to change time format. If user select 12 hour format, its display time in 12 hour if user select 24 hour then its display time in 24 hour.

I have write below code for it

```
 $(function() {

           //Timepicker
                $(".timepicker").timepicker({
                    showInputs: false,
                    showMeridian:false // for 12/24 hour time format
                });

 });
```

above code working fine. I have write below code for change time format but it did not work

```
$( "#pickhour" ).change(function() {

                    if($( "#pickhour" ).val()==1) // its set 12 hour format
                    {
                          $(".timepicker").timepicker({
                            showInputs: false,
                            showMeridian:true // for 12/24 hour time format
                        });

                    }
 });
```

Comment: Try with `$( "#pickhour" ).val()=="1"`

Comment: @ShaunakD condition works fine but time format not change as per selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem using below code

```
$(".timepicker").timepicker('remove');
```

My code

```
$( "#pickhour" ).change(function() {

 $(".timepicker").timepicker('remove');

                    if($( "#pickhour" ).val()==1) // its set 12 hour format
                    {
                          $(".timepicker").timepicker({
                            showInputs: false,
                            showMeridian:true // for 12/24 hour time format
                        });

                    }
 });
```